# i try to make the code open file inside a function, but i'm getting error

Tags: python

```
myfile.write ('name : '+fill_data({'name'})+'\n')
TypeError: fill_data() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

```py
    def safeit():
        myfile = open('data_user.txt', 'w+')
        myfile.write ('name : '+fill_data({'name'})+'\n')

    def fill_data():
        name = input ('enter name : ')
        print ('name : '+name)

    def runprogram():
        safeit()
        fill_data()
        quest = input ('add data ? (Y/N) : ')
        if quest == 'Y':
            runprogram()
        else:
            print('thanks to visit us')
            exit()

    runprogram()
```

Comment: Just as the error says, you're calling `fill_data()` with a parameter inside `safeit()` but the function definition doesn't have any parameters. It's also unclear what you want to achieve with `fill_data({'name'})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error specifies your `fill_data` function doesn't take any argument.There are two ways you can fix it:

- `return` the name variable from the `fill_data` function and assign
  it to a variable inside the `safeit` function
- take the user input inside the `safeit` function itself

I would suggest you to go with the second one as the `fill_data` function seems to be useless other than taking user input which can also be done within `safeit` without any issues:

I would suggest the following fix:

```py
def safeit():
    myfile = open('data_user.txt', 'w+')
    name = input('enter name : ')
    print ('name : '+name)
    myfile.write ('name : '+ name + '\n')

def runprogram():
    safeit()
    quest = input ('add data ? (Y/N) : ')
    if quest == 'Y':
        runprogram()
    else:
        print('thanks to visit us')
        # exit()    # you need not call this as the programme will exit on it's own 

runprogram()
```

Otherwise, if you wish to make things work out the way you are doing go with the following:

```py
def safeit():
    myfile = open('data_user.txt', 'w+')
    myfile.write ('name : ' + fill_data() + '\n')    # remember you just need to call the function here

def fill_data():
    name = input ('enter name : ')
    print ('name : '+name)
    return name    # return the name variable

def runprogram():
    safeit()
    # fill_data()  you need not call this function again as you'll be calling it within safeit()
    quest = input ('add data ? (Y/N) : ')
    if quest == 'Y':
        runprogram()
    else:
        print('thanks to visit us')
        # exit()    # you need not call this as the programme will exit on it's own

runprogram()
```